# Why is xdg-mime using so much CPU?

Tags: 18.04, cpu-load, system-monitor

Every time I start Discord, I see four processes called `xdg-mime` appear in the System Monitor, each consistently using somewhere between 20-25% of a CPU.

What are these processes, and what are they doing? It seems odd that they're using so much more processing power than `discord` itself is.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, as did the people [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/discord-xdg-mime-process-eats-a-lot-of-cpu-and-discord-doesnt-start-unless-i-kill-a-xdg-process-about-spotify/114167).

One of them posted [this link](https://bune.city/2019/05/discord-and-spotify-for-linux-and-xdg-mime/) to a workaround to our problem.

Type `which xdg-mime` in the terminal. If the output is `/usr/bin/xdg-mime` then create a file called xdg-mime in `/usr/local/bin/`, containing the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ "$@" == *"x-scheme-handler/discord"* ]]; then
    /usr/bin/true
else
    /usr/bin/xdg-mime $@
fi
```

Make the file executable.

If xdg-mime is not installed at `/usr/bin/` then, instead, report back and I will try to help.

I hope the people at Discord fix the problem for real, but for now, this is good enough.